# An eigenvalue for the linear transformation $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$ be a linear transformation defined in $F$ as the vector space of all differentiable functions, so that $f(x)$ it's a differentiable function and $f'(x)$ its derivative.

As it is a linear map: $$(f+g)'=f'+g'$$ $$ (\lambda f)' = \lambda f' $$

I was wondering if any $\lambda \in  \mathbb{R}$ different from zero just escales the elements in $Im(T)$ and then, this converts $\lambda$ to an eigenvalue, doesn't it? Excuse if the question is trivial, but I'm newbie.

Comment: $f(x) = e^{\lambda x}$?

Comment: If I have $f(x)=3e^{λx}$ then $f′(x)=3λe^{λx}$ I mean, 3 is an eigenvalue, isn't it?

Comment: Do you know the definition of eigenvalue?

Comment: @Sigrid In your example we have $T(f)=\lambda f$ but not $T(f)=3f$.

Comment: Thank you, I used to have a misconception about eigenvalues. I had to study it again, now is clearer.